# How to find out what made auto-choice in package selection

Tags: opensuse, yast

Such story as from today is not very common, but happens enough to annoy me.

I execute yast -> software management, I check summary --> chess for X Windows (xboard) :-O.

I would like to trace what is the source of such auto-selection. It was not in the list a week ago, yesterday, this morning, no. Just this evening. So something has triggered such action.

How to find out what it was?